# What did Index Means in DB?

Tags: mysql, web-crawler

Whats does "indexing" mean? How it is useful to a web crawler?

Comment: lit bit....i am not getting it while reading Wikipedia.so i asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal indexing in a database and the index that a web crawler looks at are two different concepts.

Indexing in a database is a method to make looking up records by certain columns faster.

Indexing in the context of web crawlers involves storing web pages and building an index based on what's in them so as to access them by content more easily.

Comment: "building an index based" did this means DB Indexing?

Comment: @Jesvin: In this case, "index" is used in a more general sense of the word. Think of it like the index at the back of a book. In reality, it *could* be implemented using a relational database and there probably would be database indexing in that case, but it could also be implemented with an XML file, flat text file, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_indexing